# Query GitHub Pages and JavaScript libs dont't work

Tags: javascript, github-pages

I have tried to test a static website with JS libs like JQuery on a `GitHub Pages` However, it seems that the JS (main site carousel or photo carousel) is not working on GitHub Pages.

The same code locally and on localhost temporary apache work excelent.

JQuery as an example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/javascripts/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        }
    </script>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: A link to the library code would be helpful. also, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Seems like you just don't add jQuery there. 
But be sure, JS works in GH-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mixed content. Libraries are not being loaded because their scheme is `http`, while GitHub Pages is using `https`:

[image: Google chrome console errors]

You need to change all the resources routes to match `https` protocols. If the resources websites do not allow you to do that, then you may want to download the libraries and upload to your page, instead of using CDNs. Links will go like this:

```
<script src='relative/server/folder/to/jquery.min.js' />
```

Also, you may want to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) for further information and instructions.

---

Another points you sould fix:

- Your website, after loading jQuery, `$` is not defined, but `jQuery` does. You should fix this, or use `jQuery` instead of `$`.
- After loading your carousssel with `jQuery("#mojbanner").load("assets/revslider/moj_slider.html");`, `assets/revslider/moj_slider.html` contains more http content (instead of https). You should fix this html too.
- Try fixing all the errors you see on the Chrome (or Firefox, or whatever explorer) debugging console.

Comment: I have changed the `http` to `https` but still the libs do not work. The resource websites allows it and here is the new version [Changed LInk](https://focia.github.io/index.html)

Comment: Check your html. You are loading jquery twice; one with `http`, and the other with `https`. Also, jQuery is not accesible via Google debug tools, so it's probably that the library is not being loaded correctly. Also, what's the jQuery `gMap` method for? It's actually not defined anywhere. And finally, change your ocurrences from `$` to `jQuery` (the javascript complais that `$` is not defined).

Comment: Sorry last commit didn't got the changes correct. It tends to loead jQuery now. However, the problem is that my dev console show that jquery.min.js that imports the google fonts from CDN  but build with hard coded the link with `http` instaead of `httpS`. Can I fix it by using some other jquery.min.js version?

Comment: @mCs You should probably open a new question about that.

Comment: I didn't see your edit so its ok now. Thanks I have accepted your ansewer.